# Network request failed in react native using fetch

Tags: react-native

I am developing a react native android application in which I need to fetch data from server, so I used `fetch` api for that. My code :

```
 cashOnDelivery(){

  var result  = this.props.navigation.getParam('result')

   result["qty"] = this.state.quantity
   result["booking_date"] = this.state.date_obj
   result["booking_time"] = this.state.time
   result["booking_amt"] = this.state.total



   var uid = result["user_id"]
   var serviceid = result["service_id"]
   var loc_name = result["location_name"]
   var loc_lat = result["location_lat"]
   var loc_long = result["location_long"]
   var vehicleid = result["vehicle_id"]
   var makeid = result["make_id"]
   var modelid = result["model_id"]
   var colorid = result["color_id"]
   var vehiclereg = result["vehicle_reg_num"]
   var fuelid = result["fuel_id"]
   var fuelsubid = result["fuel_subtype_id"]
   var qty = result["qty"]
   var bookingdate = result["booking_date"]
   var bookingtime = result["booking_time"]
   var bookingamt = result["booking_amt"]

   var formData = new FormData();


   formData.append('user_id', uid);
   formData.append('service_id',serviceid );
   formData.append('location_name',loc_name );
   formData.append('location_lat',loc_lat );
   formData.append('location_long',loc_long );
   formData.append('vehicle_id',vehicleid );
   formData.append('make_id', makeid);
   formData.append('model_id', modelid);
   formData.append('color_id', colorid);
   formData.append('vehicle_reg_num',vehiclereg );
   formData.append('fuel_id',fuelid );
   formData.append('fuel_subtype_id',fuelsubid );
   formData.append('qty',qty );
   formData.append('booking_date', bookingdate);
   formData.append('booking_time',bookingtime );
   formData.append('booking_amt', bookingamt);
    formData.append('payment_method',"cash")

       fetch('http://link.com', {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
       },
       body: formData

     }).then((response) => response.json())
           .then((responseJson) => {

              ToastAndroid.show(JSON.stringify(responseJson),ToastAndroid.LONG)
           if(!responseJson.error){
            // ToastAndroid.show(responseJson.message,ToastAndroid.LONG)
                this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")

               }else{

                 }

           }).catch((error) => {
            ToastAndroid.show(error.toString(),ToastAndroid.LONG)
           });
}
```

But when `cashOnDelivery()` is called then it gives me error.Network request failed.My internet connection is good and I am using Live server. Why I am facing this issue?

Comment: Do you have permission to use network ?

Comment: yes i have added it already

Comment: replace `http` with `https` (if possible) will most likely fix your issue

Comment: nope!! it didnt works

Comment: are you on android ? or iOS ?

Comment: try replacing 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' with 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'